# How do I stop varbinary data from being truncated to 256kb when reading from an SQL Server database using adodb for php

Tags: sql-server, adodb

I am writing code for a client of ours which is designed to read an image from a SQL Server database into a file in a caching directory.

The binary data is being truncated at 262144 bytes (256kb).  The column is of type varbinary(max), and we are using the ADOdb for Php to access the database.  What is the cause of the truncation, and how do we prevent it?

Attached is code used to perform the connection:

```
$conn_image = ADONewConnection('odbc_mssql');
$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=servername;Database=database;";
$conn_image->Connect($dsn,username,password);

$query = "SELECT
          Personnel.Text4, 
          Images.Image
          FROM Images
          LEFT JOIN Personnel ON Images.ParentId = Personnel.ObjectId
          WHERE Personnel.Text4 = '12345'
          ";

$result = $conn_image->Execute($query);

if (!$result) 
         print $conn_image->ErrorMsg();
else
    while (!$result->EOF) {
        if (!empty($result->fields[0])) {
            $filename = $result->fields[0] . ".jpg";
            $rawdata =  $result->fields[1];

            $size_to_write = strlen($rawdata);
            $bytes_written = 0;

            $file = fopen( "test" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename,'w');
            while ($bytes_written < $size_to_write) {
                $bw = fwrite($file, substr($rawdata, $bytes_written));
                $bytes_written += $bw;
            }

             $result->MoveNext();
        }

    }
```

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition, Version 9.00.1399.06

If I'm reading the information correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still on SQL Server 2000 you need to deal with BLOBs [like this](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/ADO.NET_2.0_Performance_Guidelines_-_Binary_Large_Objects).  Regardless, using the `reader.GetBytes()` method is likely what you're looking for.  Microsoft provides an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: I'm using the Php ADOdb library (an oversight in the original post, which I have since rectified).  I'll look into whether it has GetBytes() as well though.

Answer (score 0):

With ADOdb you can open up the adodb.inc.php file and you'll see the line:

var $maxblobsize = 262144;

You can change it to be a greater value.